# static_url calling in Tornado

Tags: python, url, static, tornado

I am a beginner to Python and Tornado web framework. When I was studying the template part in the book "[Introduction to Tornado](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021292.do)", one line confused me:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("style.css") }}">
```

How can the application know where to call the function `static_url` when there is no library imported to the namespace? I found `static_url()` in Tornado's web module, but I can not figure out how can this function be successfully called in that template file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **RequestHandler** class has a method **get_template_namespace()**, documented [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_namespace). If you click the source link then you'll see [how it creates a dictionary](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.4/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.get_template_namespace) where **'static_url'** is set to **self.static_url**.